# Set jQuery countdown time from 50000 seconds

Tags: jquery, jquery-countdown

i am using jQuery Countdown: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Example usage of this script is:

```
$(selector).countdown({since: new Date(2010, 12-1, 25)});
```

You have to set the full date, what if i have only total amount of time in seconds? I mean i want to set countdown from 50000 seconds and automatically transform it in to a days:hours:seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to get the current date and add 50000 seconds to it. You could do it like the following

```
$("#countdown").countdown({
    until: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (50000 * 1000))
});
```

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qhBWY/)**

Comment: Nice, can you explain please - why i have to 50.000 * 1000? What is 1000? And what if there not 50.000, but 150.000 seconds? Will it convert to a days also?

Comment: @Heihachi Time is in milliseconds. Since you want 50,000 seconds, you need to multiply 50,000 by 1,000 to convert from seconds to milliseconds.

Comment: @Heihachi I haven't seen it say NaN in my example. Can you tell me how to replicate it?

Comment: Can you check it here: http://cosmosgroup.kz/shop just press refresh few times then you will see NaN

Comment: @Heihachi I noticed sometimes when I refresh the page `views-field-unpublish-countdown` text is `1 second`. The following fails `seconds.replace("seconds", "")` because of the s at the end of seconds. So you end up doing `"1 second" * 1000` which is why you get NaN.

Comment: Just opened chrome developer tools and set a breakpoint. Then refreshed the page about 10 times. Noticed something odd when the text wasn't being removed from the string.

Comment: Now i fixed both seconds and second no more this word. But i have faced a new problem when sometimes i refresh the page timer goes to 00:00:01

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44448/discussion-between-danny-and-heihachi)

Answer (score 2):

I've just written a little function to do a counter for you just incase you want to have more control.

```
countDown($('#selector'), 300);

function countDown(selector, seconds){
    var oneSecond = 1;
    var passedSeconds = 0;
    var timeLeft = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(
        function(){
            passedSeconds += oneSecond;
            timeLeft = seconds-passedSeconds;
            if(timeLeft > 0 ){
                selector.text(getTimer(timeLeft));
            }else{
                selector.text('Time out');
                clearInterval(interval);
            }

        },
        oneSecond*1000);
}

function getTimer(timeLeft){
    var litteralDuration = '';
    var s = parseInt(timeLeft);
    var d = Math.floor(s / 86400);
    s %= 86400;
    var h = Math.floor(s / 3600);
    s %= 3600;
    var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
    s %= 60;


    if(d > 0){
        litteralDuration += (d == 1) ? '1 D ' :  d + ' Ds ' ;
    }
    if(h > 0){
        litteralDuration += (h == 1) ? '1 H ' : h + ' Hs ' ;
    }
    if(m > 0){
        litteralDuration += (m == 1) ? '1 M ' : m + ' Ms ' ;
    }
    if(s > 0){
        litteralDuration += (s == 1) ? '1 S ' :  s + ' Ss ' ;
    }

    return litteralDuration;
}
```

Here is a JS Fiddle for it:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sf7Fc/)

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, mate it works, but it's way longer than a Danny solution, shame i can't accept you both.

Comment: No worries at all, some people like more control is all :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var now = new Date();
var later = new Date(now.getTime() + 50000000); // 50000s == 50000000ms
$('#countdown').countdown({until: later});
```